# zepto $.type() function

Tags: jquery-plugins, porting, zepto

I'm currently trying to make the [jquery tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin zepto compatible.

according to the [zepto documentation](http://zeptojs.com/#%24.type) in version 1.0 there should be a function called `$.type()` (i'm using the latest 1.0rc)
but whenever i try to call this function i recieve the following error:

`Object function (a,b){return w.init(a,b)} has no method 'type'`

has someone has a quick answer/fix for that?

thx

Comment: There is no `$.type()` method in 1.0rc1 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDdde/)). It might have been forgotten, or maybe the plan is to only add it in the stable 1.0 release.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this has helped me to find another solution quite quickly! i'll post the "rewritten" plugin soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case `typeof()` did the job for my needs.

since zepto is finally out in version 1.0 it has $.type support as well.